# Speech recognition on non-English window systems

Tags: c#, winforms, speech-recognition, speech

It isn't possible to use speech recognition application on my Dutch windows system, because it is only available on the English version.

Now I want to integrate speech recognition into a winforms application using c#, I prefer the English language of course.

Is this possible? Are there libraries for this?

Answer (score -1):

Here is a link to a Microsoft web page on its speech recognition software :
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh361683%28v=office.14%29.aspx
It provides provides an overview and examples for implementing speech recognition in a Windows Forms application, according to the website.

For voice recording with C# source code, here is another link:
http://voicerecorder.codeplex.com/
This software does not provide speech recognition capabilities, but shows how to record audio using .Net framework, display audio wave forms and save audio in MP3 or WAV format.

Comment: how about a synopsis of what those two links say, link only answers are frowned upon because links can break rendering the answer useless.